# How to convert a date format

Tags: mysql

Table

```
ID CardDate

001 09/01/2010
002 08/05/2010
```

DateFormat in the table : (mm/dd/yyyy)

I want to make a datediff between cardDate & systemDate

Query

```
Select id, datediff(carddate, curdate()) as actualdate group by id from table
```

The above query is showing a null value in actualdate column becuase carddate format is wrong.

How to change the Carddate format like this yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT t.id,
            DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(t.carddate, '%m/%d/%Y'), CURDATE)
   FROM TABLE t
```

I don't see the need for the GROUP BY you have in your query - it's in the wrong spot, should be after the FROM clause (and WHERE for that matter) if you still want it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at MySQL [GET_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_get-format) and [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)